# Select all values from first table and ONLY first value from second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I want to select all values from *Users* and min of `dateUsed` in Code table. How can I do that?

I've tried this:

```
    SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, u.fbId, q.dateUsed, u.codesLeft
  FROM Users u
  inner join Code q on  u.Id = q.userId
```

But it's selecting all values from the Code and Users tables.

P.S. Adding distinct has no effect

Comment: what is "first" code? rows in table are unordered in general case

Comment: What do you mean by first Code? The earliest date?

Comment: Can you add the result and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding distinct has no effect

As a rule of thumb, `DISTINCT` helps for a single-column `SELECT`s. With multiple columns you need to go for "big guns" - the `GROUP BY` clause.

In order for that to work you need to make sure that each item that you select is either a `GROUP BY` column, or has a suitable aggregation function:

```
SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, u.fbId, MIN(q.dateUsed) as dateUsed, u.codesLeft
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Code q ON u.Id = q.userId
GROUP BY u.firstName, u.lastName, u.fbId, u.codesLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

Scalar Sub Query

```
SELECT u.firstName,
u.lastName,
u.fbId,
(SELECT TOP 1 dateUsed
    FROM Code as q WHERE u.Id = q.userId
    ORDER BY dateUsed ASC),
u.codesLeft
FROM Users u
```

OR CTE

```
;WITH SEQ as (
SELECT userId, MIN(DateUsed) as FirstDate, MAX(DateUsed) as lastDate
FROM Code GROUP BY userID)

SELECT... u.*, q.FirstDate, q.LastDate
FROM Users as u
JOIN SEQ as q ON u.ID = q.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see more from the Code table than just the date, you can use a correlated subquery in the join:

```
SELECT  u.firstName, u.lastName, u.fbId, q.dateUsed, u.codesLeft,
        q.codeVal, q.ipUsed
FROM    Users u
join    Code q
    on  q.userId = u.Id
    and q.dateUsed =(
        select  Min( dateUsed )
        from    Code
        where   userID = q.userID );
```